# Vue3 style directive with background-image produces 404 Error

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3

I am assingning a reactive `image link` fetched from a `database` through `axios.get` like so:

```
<div class="main-image" :style="{'background-image': 'url(' + state.articles.image[0] + ')'}">
```

Everything works fine, the background image of the div is changed correctly. The only problem is that my console throws:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

Apparently this indicates that the `url` is pointing to nowhere, but how is that even possible when the `background-image` is displayed correctly? Nowhere in my `CSS` have I set a `background-image` property, only `background: no-repeat center` but even if I remove those the error persists. Any ideas how to get rid of the `404`?

Running `console.log(state.articles.image[0])` before sending it to the `template` produces the correct image link:

```
storage/brrAlEXfmEvoqjXiRhgalgzT9f2MfbX07Q4wDL0i.jpg
```

and even if I output the link in the template (in a h-tag for example) it shows the correct link, so what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template will be rendered before `state.articles.image[0]` is known. The div tag is rendered and the browser will try to obtain the yet `undefined` background image url. One way around this will be to render the `<div>` only when the state is ready.

```
<div v-if="state.articles && state.articles.image[0]" class="main-image" :style="{'background-image': 'url(' + state.articles.image[0] + ')'}">
```